# is it possible to access data from one scala macro in another?

Tags: scala, macros

I'd like to use scala macros for timing certain critical areas in my program.

In C, I did something like this (pseudo code)

```
#ifdef TIMING
val start = now
#endif

do something expensive

#ifdef TIMING
print "something expensive took " +  now - start + " ms"
#endif
```

this requires the second block to have access to the variable start from the first block. Can this be done in scala macros? Or is there another way to achieve this by turning the check on or off at compile time?

Comment: Macro are functions so passing args work the same